# How to install Oracle 18C XE package on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, 18.04, software-installation, oracle, rpm

I have downloaded Oracle 18C XE the rpm file, but I don't know how to install the database.

Comment: Be careful when trying to install RPMs in Ubuntu, the underlying package management system is **NOT** RPM based for Ubuntu, so you may end up clobbering software dependencies, already installed libraries, etc. in your attempts to install the RPM.  (RPMs are for Red Hat based systems like RHEL or CentOS, not Ubuntu)

Comment: I apologize for flagging this question earlier, I didn't realize I could just comment.  Any hoot...I don't think this should be considered a duplicate of "how to install .rpm packages".  It's specifically about Oracle 18c XE, which isn't as straightforward as just using alien.  There are numerous system configuration changes that would need to be made if (depending which version of Oracle XE) the alien process doesn't fail.

Comment: @WillSams Currently the only answers talk about alien and other conversion tools. Do you have a more in-depth answer you would like to provide?

Comment: Seth, no.  However, those previous answers aren't good answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Alien

#### Description

> Convert and install rpm and other packages.
>   Alien allows you to convert LSB, Red Hat, Stampede and Slackware Packages into Debian packages, which can be installed with dpkg or apt.

It can also generate packages of any of the other formats.

This is a tool only suitable for binary packages.

#### Install

```
sudo apt install alien
```

#### Usage

```
alien -d your_rpm_file.rpm
```

Then install it with `apt`:

```
sudo apt install ./your_rpm_file.deb
```

---

I would google for a snap or docker image instead of converting a rpm pkg, eg:

- https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles
- https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/README.md

For more info visit:

- https://github.com/oracle/docker-images
- https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/README.md

Comment: See https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/README.md for more info on the "docker-way (tm)".

Comment: On my machine alien does not convert or install the rpm containing oracle xe successfully.

Comment: Unpacking of 'oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm' failed at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package/Rpm.pm line 168.

Answer (score 0):

On MY Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (YMMV),

```
$ man -k RPM
rpm (8)              - RPM Package Manager
rpm2archive (8)      - Extract archive archive from RPM Package Manager (RPM) package.
rpm2cpio (8)         - Extract cpio archive from RPM Package Manager (RPM) package.
rpm_execcon (3)      - get or set the SELinux security context used for executing a new process
rpmatch (3)          - determine if the answer to a question is affirmative or negative
rpmbuild (8)         - Build RPM Package(s)
rpmdb (8)            - RPM Database Tool
rpmdeps (8)          - Generate RPM Package Dependencies
rpmgraph (8)         - Display RPM Package Dependency Graph
rpmkeys (8)          - RPM Keyring
rpmquery (8)         - RPM Package Manager
rpmsearch (1sr)      - surfraw(1) search tools
rpmsign (8)          - RPM Package Signing
rpmspec (8)          - RPM Spec Tool
rpmverify (8)        - RPM Package Manager
tap2rpm (1)          - create RPM packages which wrap .tap files
```

These are available from the package manager:

```
$ for i in rpm rpm2archive rpm2cpio rpm_execcon rpmatch rpmbuild rpmdb rpmdeps rpmgraph rpmkeys rpmquery rpmsearch rpmsign rpmspec rpmverify tap2rpm ; do dpkg -S $(type -p $i) 2>/dev/null; done
rpm: /usr/bin/rpm
rpm2cpio: /usr/bin/rpm2archive
rpm2cpio: /usr/bin/rpm2cpio
rpm: /usr/bin/rpmbuild
rpm: /usr/bin/rpmdb
rpm: /usr/bin/rpmgraph
rpm: /usr/bin/rpmkeys
rpm: /usr/bin/rpmquery
rpm: /usr/bin/rpmsign
rpm: /usr/bin/rpmspec
rpm: /usr/bin/rpmverify
python-twisted-core: /usr/bin/tap2rpm
```